# Android - toolbar title disappears when hidden/shown too fast

Tags: android, toolbar, title

I am experiencing a weird issue. If I change the toolbar title too fast in a short interval, it magically disappears:

```
09-23 12:06:33.461 D/MainActivity: #ViewModel updated title to null
09-23 12:06:33.609 D/MainActivity: #ViewModel updated title to My New Title
```

Code:

```
mViewModel.getToolbarTitle().observe(this, title -> {
    Timber.d("#ViewModel updated title to %s", title);
    mToolbar.setTitle(title);
});
```

There should be no initial title (it is loading data from the server) and new (downloaded) one should be displayed upon loading. If the initial title is not null, it is working correctly, but I guess there is some issue with show/hide title animation.

Don't you know how to avoid this issue?

Comment: Kindly share the code where you are seting the title to toolbar..

Comment: I added the code.

Answer (score 1):

Have you set setDisplayShowTitleEnabled to true in onCreate of the Activity?

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
```

Comment: I am sorry but has about 1600 lines of code and the rest is completely irrelevant to the toolbar.